# count() returning zero hits in post_save

Tags: django, signals

We have a Dialog and a Comment object. We have a denormalized field,  num_comments, on Dialog to keep track of the number of comments. When a new comment is saved (or deleted) we want to increase/decrease this value properly.

```
# sender=Comment, called post_save and post_delete
def recalc_comments(sender, instance, created=False, **kwargs):
    # Comments that will be deleted might not have a dialog (when dialog gets deleted)
    if not hasattr(instance, "dialog"):
        return

    dialog = instance.dialog
    dialog.update(
        num_comments = sender.public.filter(dialog=dialog).count(),
        num_commentators = sender.public.filter(dialog=dialog).aggregate(c=Count('user',     distinct=True))["c"],
)
```

The problem that has started to appear is that the query for num_comments returns zero for the first comment posted. This does not happen every time, and only in cases with aprox. > 1000 comments in the result set (not much, I know...).

Could it be that the Comment has not yet been saved to the database when the count() is performed? To complicate things further we are using Johnny Cache (with memcached) as a layer between the ORM and database.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try at least to test this with cache disabled. Is the problem still there?

Comment: Can you post your models so we can see if the problem es anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to do denormalization of your database scheme for best query performance. In this case I can recommend you application designed specially for this purpose - [django-composition](https://github.com/daevaorn/django-composition)

As documentation said:

> django-composition provides the abstract way to denormalize data from
>   your models in simple declarative way through special generic model
>   field called CompositionField.
>
> Most cases of data denormalization are pretty common so
>   django-composition has several "short-cuts" fields that handles most
>   of them.
>
> CompositionField is django model field that provides interface to data
>   denormalization.

You also can use [this shortcut ForeignCountField](https://github.com/daevaorn/django-composition/issues/3). It help to count number of  objects related by foreignkey.